# Why the constraint always holds in soft margin SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

In the soft margin SVM, the loss minimization function is given as -

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvvBS.gif]

Subject to $y_i(w^Tx_i + b) \geq 1 - \varepsilon_i$ and $\varepsilon_i \geq 0$

The 2nd constraint will always be true for any value of $x_i$,

$y_i(w^Tx_i + b) \geq 1 - \varepsilon_i$

and $\varepsilon = 1-(y_i(w^tx_i + b))$

So, for misclassified points, the constraint will be,

$y_i(w^Tx_i + b) \geq 1 - (1 - (y_i(w^Tx_i + b)))$

which will be,

$y_i(w^Tx_i + b) \geq (y_i(w^Tx_i + b))$

This means the constraint always holds.
So, what is the point of using the constraint?